# NoClassDefFoundError when using Flyway

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, flyway

The following call (I replaced sensitive information with <>):

```
flyway
-url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//<server_name>:<port_number>/<service_name>
-jarDirs=<jar_directory_paths>
-locations=filesystem:<path>
-user=<user> -password=<password> info
```

Produce the following error:

> Flyway output: Flyway 4.2.0 by Boxfuse
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   oracle/dms/console/DMSConsole
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.DMSFactory.(DMSFactory.java:44)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.createDMSSensors(PhysicalConnection.java:4202)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.(PhysicalConnection.java:628)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.(T4CConnection.java:217)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:28)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:537)
>       at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.DriverDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverDataSource.java:416)
>       at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:381)
>       at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:51)
>       at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1418)
>       at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.info(Flyway.java:1097)
>       at org.flywaydb.commandline.Main.executeOperation(Main.java:152)
>       at org.flywaydb.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:103) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.dms.console.DMSConsole
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>       ... 13 more

Any ideas what could be the cause?

Comment: What version of the Oracle JDBC driver do you have in the `flyway/drivers` folder?

Comment: 5 and 6

    flyway/drivers$ ls
    ojdbc5dms_g.jar
    ojdbc5dms.jar
    ojdbc5_g.jar
    ojdbc5.jar
    ojdbc6dms_g.jar
    ojdbc6dms.jar
    ojdbc6_g.jar
    ojdbc6.jar
    simplefan.jar

Oracle Instant Client version is 11.2.0

Comment: Could it be that version 8 is needed.

Comment: The missing class in the exception message is certainly in the v8 driver

Comment: Thank you very much Julia. I'm waiting for the team to update the Oracle JDBC driver and let you know if it resolved the issue.

Comment: Any news on this issue?

Comment: I'm working on it. The team installed 12.2 but the JDBC drivers weren't installed. I'll come back to you once it's done. Thank you for you follow up.

Comment: So yes, the issue was the version of the JDBC drivers. Thank you Julia for the help.

Comment: I'll let you add the answer and will flag it as Accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing class in the exception message is in the v8 Oracle JDBC driver and subsequent ones. You should be able to resolve the problem by upgrading your installation to the latest version of the driver.